# Django method returning

Tags: python, django

With a method to get all related connections, is it better to simply return a queryset, or iterate through the queryset to return a list of IDs?

## example code:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name="foos")

class Bar(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def get_foos(self):
        #this is the method to focus on for the question
```

to return a queryset all that would need to be in `get_foos` is the following:

```
return self.foos.all()
```

but to get a list of ids, it would have to look as such:

```
foos = self.foos.all()
ids = []
for foo in foos:
    ids.append(foo.pk)
return ids
```

I was looking through an API, and they used the latter, but I don't really understand why you would ever actually do that if you could just do a one-liner like the former! **Can someone please explain the benefits of these methods and if there are specific cases in which one is better than the other?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get Foo ids in one line:

```
ids = self.foos.values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

Using id list is more efficient if used in other expressions, e.g.:

```
my_query.filter(foo__pk__in=ids)
```

Comment: Just for the record: with at least MySQL it's more efficient to write the filter clause as `my_query.filter(foo__pk__in=list(ids))`, as it will avoid a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you really saw something like your second snippet in some published app, then you can send them a patch (and probably more than one, since chances are you'll find a lot of bad code in this app). Point is : there's a lot of very poorly written Django apps around. As Niekas posted, you can get the same result with whay better performances in a no-brainer one-liner.

Now wrt/ why return a list of pks instead of a full queryset, well, sometimes that's really just what you need, and sometimes that's just silly - depends on the context, really.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a better vs worse scenario. The ID list can also be generated with a one-liner:

```
list(self.foos.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

It's sometimes good practice for a function to return the minimal or least powerful representation of the data requested. Maybe you don't want callers to have access to the `queryset` object.

Maybe those IDs are going to the template rendering engine, and you'd rather not have templates with write access to querysets, for example.

Comment: `[foo.pk for foo in self.foos.all()]` is better written `list(self.foos.values_list('pk', flat=True))`.